# Adding a span tag to main menu items

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I insert a <span> </span> tag inside the <a> </a> tag on my main menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-do-i-insert-a-span-span-tag-inside-the-a-a-tag-on-my-main-menu)

I tried the code found in [How do I insert a <span> </span> tag inside the <a> </a> tag on my main menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-do-i-insert-a-span-span-tag-inside-the-a-a-tag-on-my-main-menu), and I have a problem with it: while it does add the span tags, it also strips out the main menu's unordered list and classes.

How do I add the span tags **inside** the main menu links while also keeping the unordered list and the list menu classes?

Comment: Hello jive, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. What is the difference between this question, and the other one? Did you read all the answers given for the other question?

Comment: @kiamlaluno . Yes I did read the answers. The difference is that the code provided (on both questions) strips out the main menu `ul` and `li` and the attribute classes. The output for the answer results in [this](http://pastie.org/1768286) and the output I'm looking for is [this](http://pastie.org/1768299).(please also see my comment below) I guess my question should have been: How do I add the span tags inside the main menu links while also keeping the `ul` and the `li` tags and associated classes and not converting the opening and closing tags to gt and lt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7:

```php
function THEMENAME_links__system_MENUNAME_menu($variables) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $output .= l('<li' . drupal_attributes(array('class' => $class)) . '>' .'<span>'. check_plain($link['title']) .'</span>' . '</li>', $link['href'], $link);
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Is the `<li>` inside the `<a>`?

Comment: No, the `<a>` is supposed to be inside the  `<li>` tag. However, the above code strips out the classed that drupal 7 gives for each menu item. The above code outputs this:
[link](http://pastie.org/1768286)

And the output I'm looking for is this:[link](http://pastie.org/1768286). In your code, the assigned menu classes in the `<li>` tag (`<li class="menu-501">`) are missing.  It also replaces any opening and closing html tag with &gt and &lt . @Westie  @kiamlaluno

Comment: can someone with EDIT priviledges pleaes fix the highlight  l('<li' . drupal_attributes