# How do I insert a <span> </span> tag outside the <a> </a> tag on my main menu

Tags: routes

I have been scouring the web trying to find a way to get a  tag just AFTER each of my main menu items. Looking at [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-do-i-insert-a-span-span-tag-inside-the-a-a-tag-on-my-main-menu) I am able to get a  tag in there, but it's INSIDE the link. I just don't want it to be a link.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I just don't know enough PHP to place it outside the link. This is what I have so far in my template.php:

```
function motg_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;


if ($element['#below']) {
$sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
}

if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu"){

$element['#title'] .= '<span class="description">'.$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'].'</span>';
}

$output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your menu link to be like this `<li><a>Link 1</a><span>Description</span></li>`, ie., the description is outside the `<a>` tags, then try the code below.

```
function motg_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;


  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu" && isset($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'])){
    $description = '<span class="description">' . $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] . '</span>';
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . $description."</li>\n";
}
```

The reason your code didn't work was, you used the description tag within the `l()` function. In drupal the `l()` function always renders an `<a>` tag and so the description was inside the `<a>` tag.