# Add a span and class to menu items that has children

Tags: blocks

I'm customizing the main menu using the Menu Block Module. I need to set a class for all li elements that has children regardless of level. I might need to add a span inside the a-tags as well. Is it possible to do this in the template.php or do I need to alter module files. I would preffere not to edit module files if possible.

Like:

```
<li class="expanded menu-mlid-871 has-children">
   <a href="...">Menu item name<span class="test"></span></a>
   <ul> <!-- (children items) --> <ul>
</li>
```

Is this doable with some:

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) { ...?... }
```

[edit]

Menu items with no children has the `class="leaf"`. It should be possible to style the menu items `li` (has children) and then cancel the rule-set for the class `li.leaf` (has no children). The span can be added by using some `li::after` rule-set and removed with eg `li.leaf::after {display:none;}`

In this way it can be solved with CSS only. The problem is I need to use the  `<span class="test"></span>` for a click event. So at least I need a real span inside the `li a` witch is not a "leaf".

Anyone who can help me with a theme functions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Menu items with no children has the `class="leaf"`. It is possible to style the menu items `li` (has children) and then cancel the rule-set for the class `li.leaf` (has no children).

A span can be added to all li's (set to display:none for leafs).
[How do I insert a <span> </span> tag inside the <a> </a> tag on my main menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-do-i-insert-a-span-span-tag-inside-the-a-a-tag-on-my-main-menu#answer-16412)